# Prevent deleting string from textbox after reaching to certain length in Angular 2 & 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to prevent the user from deleting certain length of string from textbox in Angular2+.

I want some text like "abcd" to be fixed in textbox such that user cannot delete it. It would act like pre-string.

`<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="fname" placeholder="Enter a name here">`

where
`fname: string = 'abcd';`

I want to prevent pressing backspace or delete button if the text reached to specified length while deleting the text from textbox.

Anyone can help me with this?

Here is plunker: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5sgoD1VhUxkARlgwyfBU?p=preview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can handle event keydow

```
<input [(ngModel)]='name' (keydown)="eventHandler($event)"/>
```

**.ts**

```
  eventHandler(event){
   if(event.target.value.length == this.specificLength && (event.code == "Backspace" || event.code == "Delete")){
     return false;
   }

   return true;
  }
```

You can refer my link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6lw2tg?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @SamuelKavinLoganathan - If I put the caret at the start of the text and press the Delete key, the beginning of the string is deleted. Is that OK? I can also select all the input content and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery:

```js
$("input").keydown(function(e) {
    var oldvalue=$(this).val();
    var field=this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        if(field.value.indexOf('abcd') !== 0) {
            $(field).val(oldvalue);
        } 
    }, 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="abcd"/>
```